# Login page - Checking the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I am trying to make a simple login page, user enters ID and password, and chooses role from a dropdown list:Student, Administrator or Instructor. Here is the code:

```
protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=University;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
    //myConn.Open();
    //string strqry = "Insert into students values (" + TextBox1.Text +
    //",'" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "')";
    //SqlCommand myCom = new SqlCommand(strqry, myConn);
    //int numrow = myCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //myConn.Close();

    Int32 verify;
    string query1 = "Select count(*) from Login where ID='" + idBox.Text + "' and Password='" + passwordBox.Text + "' and Type='"+ LoginAs.Text +"'" ;
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
    con.Open();
    verify = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
    con.Close();
    if (verify > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("succesful.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("unsuccesful.aspx",true);
    }

}
```

The problem is, when i try without checking the value of the dropdown list called "LoginAs", it works fine and makes validation. But when i also check the Type, which is either Student, Administrator or Instructor it always makes unsuccesful login even though all the information is correct. Can anyone help me to find what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try by getting the selected value. `LoginAs.SelectedValue`. Also, please debug and check the formed query.

Comment: if LoginAs is dropdown then use `SelectedValue` instead of `Text`

Comment: For the sake of yourself, *please* use [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) and for the sake of your users NEVER EVER store passwords in plain text! Use hashing and salting. There should be plenty of examples here on SO for that.

Comment: Also - I would suggest moving your code out of the button logic into it's own Authentication class.  You are currently using "Magic Pushbutton" anti-pattern - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_pushbutton.  This is an easy thing to miss, but you will be happy you changed it if you (or anyone else) need to maintain this code in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use parametrized queries maybe it will be resolved and you would prevent  risks it goes like this

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", idBox.Text);
```

Comment: It's good that you accepted this answer are going to use parameters. Just imagine if I typed the username `' OR 1=1 ;--`. Or even better `'; drop table Login;--`

Answer (score 0):

The first points to check is the:

1. The all of the letters should has the same case.
2. The role should be truncated in database and in the application

But, it's preffered to use enum/int to define role of user instead of a text name.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to SqlDataReader class. You can catch if an reads occur.
Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx). While this not the case I recommend you to use a scalar function in your database or use EntityFramework or other ORM tools.